# Get value from data-attribute of selected dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to select the data attribute from the selected option of a drop-down list then place it within a textbox. This is also my second data attribute. I'm going to add code for whenever the user changes the option (code I already have written and can abstract here), but I want to get this part to work first.

HTML

```
<select class="operations-supplier" name="operations-supplier">
    <option data-selected="latam" data-capacity="100000" value="
        10">LATAM - Supplier A</option>
    <option data-selected="na" data-capacity="200000" value="20>">NA - Supplier B</option>
    <option data-selected="asia" data-capacity="300000" value="30">ASIA - Supplier C</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="operations-supplierCapacity" readonly />
```

JQuery

```
var capacityValue = $('select.operations-supplier').find(':selected').attr('data-capacity').val();
$('.operations-supplierCapacity').val(capacityValue);
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darcyvoutt/TpStt/)

Comment: `var capacityValue = $(this).find(':selected').data('capacity');`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use **[`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)** method in jQuery , Also add a **[`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event for dropdown

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select.operations-supplier').change(function() {
        var capacityValue = $('select.operations-supplier').find(':selected').data('capacity');
        $('.operations-supplierCapacity').val(capacityValue);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/TpStt/2/)

You need to wrap code within `$(document).ready(function() {...});` , to bind event after dom element is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the additional code for the change. The only thing that should be added to this is a $('select.operations-supplier').trigger('change'); after the first closing bracket of "});"

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/X4JvA/1/

```
$('.operations-supplier').change(function(){
   $('.operations-supplierCapacity').val($('.operations-supplier option:selected').attr('data-capacity'))
   //alert($('.operations-supplier option:selected').attr('data-selected'))
})
```

Answer (score 3):

In pure vanilla javascript you can use :

```
   var supplierCapacity = this.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-capacity'));
```

Example:

```js
function OnSelectChange(event) {
    document.getElementById('supplierCapacity').value = event.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-capacity'); 
}
```

```html
<select onchange="OnSelectChange(this)" class="operations-supplier" name="operations-supplier">
<option data-selected="latam" data-capacity="100000" value="10">LATAM - Supplier A</option>
<option data-selected="na" data-capacity="200000" value="20>">NA - Supplier B</option>
<option data-selected="asia" data-capacity="300000" value="30">ASIA - Supplier C</option>
</select>
<input id="supplierCapacity" type="text" class="operations-supplierCapacity" readonly />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get data using [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function as [follows](http://jsfiddle.net/Antindexer/L5HVy/):

```
$('select.operations-supplier').on('change', function() {
    var capacityValue = $('select.operations-supplier').find(':selected').data('capacity');
    $('.operations-supplierCapacity').val(capacityValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A data attribute isn't an input, and you don't need to call `.val()` on it.

The following will work just fine:

```
var capacityValue = $('select.operations-supplier').find(':selected').attr('data-capacity');
$('.operations-supplierCapacity').val(capacityValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another vanilla javascript modern approach using [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
document.querySelector(".operations-supplier").addEventListener("change", e => {
  const result = Array.from(e.target.children)
    .find(option => option.value === e.target.value)
    .getAttribute("data-capacity");

  // do what you will with the result
  console.log(result);

  document.querySelector(".operations-supplierCapacity").value = result;
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).